# Best way to store lots of data for each page in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to allow users to post coupons on different pages.  Then allow users to up-vote and down-vote each other's coupons.

How should i store this data in wordpress?

I'm trying to create a large table that has fields for page_title(company), coupon-code, up-votes, down-votes.

I'd then check what page the user is on and fill it with all the appropriate coupons.

Is this a good way to do it? Or should i be trying to add columns to a custom page type?

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom template and should use advanced custom field plugin.

[Advanced Custom Field plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)